# local check Windows active logins output for "not active"

Tags: batch-file, check-mk

I've got a little local check runnig to see if someone is logged in, in case before I connect via RDP etc.

This works fine if someone is logged in:

```
@echo off
for /F  %%A in ('"query user | find "Aktiv""') DO (
echo 0 logins-aktiv - Aktiv: %%A, Domain: %USERDOMAIN%, Host: %COMPUTERNAME%, Check: %date% %time%
)
```

[CheckMK: Login active - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z9PU.png)

But if no one is logged CheckMK tells me "Item not found in monitoring data". In that case I would like to have a breakout and a green OK with text like "*nicht aktiv*".
[CheckMK: Login not active - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMLUp.png)

I tried some IF/ELSE or IF NOT.
But I'm too new to this and can't help myself.
My idea is, if there's no input from %%A to jump to "echo 0 logins-aktiv - nicht aktiv" as a print out.

It's a picky thing I know, but I can't help me to fix it, because I don't find the right commands for that. I would like to understand and learn it.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the specific issue your submitted code is exhibiting? and what have you tried yourself to fix it? I cannot see any code in your question which determines or prints anything when nobody is active, and certainly none which uses a different color font. You therefore have multiple questions, none of which you've tried, and your submission is therefore essentially an off topic code request.

Comment: hi,
I'm not sure if it's the correct topic, it's a CheckMK feature.
I edited my first post with the IF/ELSE idea, but I couldn't make it run.

Comment: Which specific issue do you want us to assist you with? How to use `CheckMK`, is not a valid question, and should somewhere already be documented. How to use `If`/`Else` is also clearly explained in the usage information for those commands. How to use `For /F` `QUser`/`Query User`, and `Find` are also well documented. For that reason you appear either asking for direct code, research material or both, none of which are on topic. Do you know what your `For /F` loop is doing? It's running `QUser` and passing its output to `Find`, if the case sensitive string `Aktiv` is included, the `Do` is run.

Comment: Ah, ok I see.
I'm looking for an output if there's nothing in "Aktiv".

My research result code is above, that's what I've found out so far.
Maybe FOR/DO is not the right way. That's why I'm asking for hints.
https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Comment: Well you could try captuing the output from just `QUser` effectively passing all the output to the `Do` portion, _(except for error messages)_. You could do that by including all `Tokens`, and removing the string check within the parenthesized command. Then you could perform a string check against the output `%%A` in the `Do` portion as required.

Comment: It is actually a simple solution., but Could you show an actual result of both scenarios?

Comment: hi  @Gerhard, I added some screenshots of both scenarios.
I tried it again with some code, but I'm still not able to find the right programming. :/